# Mysql: Error 1054

Tags: mysql

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1054: Unknown column 'Team 1' in 'field list'
SQL Code:

```
 INSERT INTO `Project`.`Teams` (`TeamName`, `TeamID`) VALUES (Team 1, '1')
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 21 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should use quote for a string

```
INSERT INTO `Project`.`Teams` (`TeamName`, `TeamID`) VALUES ('Team 1', '1')
```

Otherwise the db engine think is a column name

and eventually  if the id is a number avoid quote for number

```
INSERT INTO `Project`.`Teams` (`TeamName`, `TeamID`) VALUES ('Team 1', 1)
```